# Snakes and Ladders

Tags: vb.net

I have to create a snakes and ladders game for a project. I have 30 spaces on my board. if the Marker goes past 30 the application crashes with :

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in appCounter.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I want the Marker to stay where it is if the number rolled would bring it past 30.

here is my code:

```
Public Class frmBoard
Dim intScore As Integer

Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    'declartions
    Dim intValue As Integer
    Dim strCounterName As String
    Dim roll As New Random()
    Dim intRoll = roll.Next(1, 7)

    'make the current counter visible
    If intScore > 0 Then
        strCounterName = "lblCounter" & intScore
        Me.Controls(strCounterName).Visible = False
    End If


    'input
    intValue = intRoll
    intScore = intScore + intValue
    strCounterName = "lblcounter" & intScore.ToString

    'output
    txtMove.Text = intRoll
    Me.Controls(strCounterName).Visible = True

    If intScore = 3 Then
        lblCounter3.Visible = False
        lblCounter22.Visible = True
        intScore = 22
    End If

    If intScore = 5 Then
        lblCounter5.Visible = False
        lblCounter8.Visible = True
        intScore = 8
    End If

    If intScore = 11 Then
        lblCounter11.Visible = False
        lblCounter26.Visible = True
        intScore = 26
    End If

    If intScore = 20 Then
        lblCounter20.Visible = False
        lblCounter29.Visible = True
        intScore = 29
    End If

    If intScore = 17 Then
        lblCounter17.Visible = False
        lblCounter4.Visible = True
        intScore = 4
    End If

    If intScore = 19 Then
        lblCounter19.Visible = False
        lblCounter7.Visible = True
        intScore = 7
    End If

    If intScore = 21 Then
        lblCounter21.Visible = False
        lblCounter9.Visible = True
        intScore = 9
    End If

    If intScore = 27 Then
        lblCounter27.Visible = False
        lblCounter1.Visible = True
        intScore = 1
    End If

    If intScore = 31 Then
        lblCounter31.Visible = False
        lblCounter1.Visible = True
        intScore = 1
    End If

    If intScore = 32 Then
        lblCounter32.Visible = False
        lblCounter1.Visible = True
        intScore = 1
    End If

    If intScore = 33 Then
        lblCounter33.Visible = False
        lblCounter1.Visible = True
        intScore = 1
    End If

    If intScore = 30 Then
        MsgBox("Winner")
    End If

    If intScore > 30 Then
        MsgBox("OvErBoArD")
    End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Note that `vba` is not the same as `vb.net`.

Comment: You would need to add some sort of check when you add the user's "roll of dice" to see `If roll + intScore > 30 Then` leave the counter alone, `Else add the roll to counter`.

Comment: I'm new to this and my teacher doesn't go into very much of an explanation, sorry Bjorn

Comment: Unless this is the only thing you will ever write, this wont be the first time you run into the NRE.  The VB answer posted on the link might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show your user that they went over and skip the adding of the roll to the total to leave them in place.

Change:

```
'input
intValue = intRoll
intScore = intScore + intValue
strCounterName = "lblcounter" & intScore.ToString
```

To:

```
'input
intValue = intRoll
If intScore + intValue > 30 Then
    MsgBox "OvErBoArD"
Else
    intScore = intScore + intValue
End If
strCounterName = "lblcounter" & intScore.ToString
```

Answer (score -2):

Since there are only 30 counters when intScore goes over 30 it will throw this exception.

Add an If statement to your input as follows:

```
'input
intValue = intRoll
If intscore + intvalue < 30 then 
intscore=intscore + intvalue
End if

strCounterName = "lblcounter" & intScore.ToString
```

This way it will not go over thirty before it sets the lblcounter and will not bug out

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the user's criteria of "I want the Marker to stay where it is if the number rolled would bring it past 30."